# Alternative to using werkzeug to integrate Plotly Dash to an existing Flask App?

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash, werkzeug, waitress

I currently have a flask app hosted on a `waitress` production server. I'd like to integrate plotly dash into my application [without using `werkzeug`](https://dash.plotly.com/integrating-dash) but cannot find any resources on how to do this.

The existing `werkzeug` solution:

```
from werkzeug.wsgi import DispatcherMiddleware
from werkzeug.serving import run_simple

from flask_app import flask_app
from app1 import app as app1
from app2 import app as app2

application = DispatcherMiddleware(flask_app, {
    '/app1': app1.server,
    '/app2': app2.server,
})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_simple('localhost', 8050, application)
```

**How do I do this without `werkzeug`?**

Comment: Not sure why you're trying to do this.  Are you aware that Werkzeug is a Flask dependency?  Perhaps if you really want to avoid `DispatcherMiddleware` you could launch a separate waitress process to serve each endpoint, but my understanding is this re-introduces the issue DispatcherMiddleware aims to solve; combining several WSGI apps into one.  Can you clarify?

Comment: I appreciate the depth of this clarifying question. The ambiguity is owed to my lack of understand with the DevOps of Flask. (I had not known werkzeug is a flask dependency.) To answer your q: I'm hosting this app on a virtual machine which gives me errors with a werkzeug server but not with a waitress server... I couldn't debug it so here I am...

Comment: It may be worth adding these errors to this question (or logging a separate relevant question) to get to the bottom of the issues with your werkzeug deployment.  At present this sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  You'd probably get more help if you describe the initial issue (especially given that the werkzeug method is mentioned in the official docs which you linked).

Comment: Fair! Will modify. @v25

Comment: Got a solution to this @v25 -- frustrating and hilarious. If I pass the main server (`app=Flask()`) to the dash app, there is no need for middleware... o_O The whole thing operates as one fully integrated app... Has to do with wsgi somehow, not entirely sure.